# fetching an object from db using the "offset" parameter chrage too many SMALL OPERATIONS

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Im getting objects from google app engine db using the offset parameter:

```
MyModel.all(keys_only=True).filter("level =", level).filter("state >=", state).fetch(limit, offset)
```

when im looking at the app stats im seing that the charged SMALL OPERATIONS is increasing in direct relation with the offset value.

is it possible? im expecting to be able to fetch objects from a certain point and pay only for the fetched data, I think im doing something wrong here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query with `offset` parameter bills you for all skipped entities plus the fetched entities. This is not clearly stated in the docs, you need to [dig a bit](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference):

`Note: Like the offset parameter for the fetch() method, an OFFSET in a GQL query string does not reduce the number of entities fetched from the datastore. It only affects which results are returned by the fetch() method. A query with an offset has performance characteristics that correspond linearly with the offset size plus the limit size.`

You'd be better off using [`run()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery_run) with cursors.

Comment: thanks a lot peter, i would try my luck with cursors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you're doing, but if you're iterating through a set of data in chunks, you'd be better off using cursors rather than offsets.

Comment: hey daniel thanks for the reply. I do not iterate over a set ofo data, my target is to get 5 models from a certain table randomly, using some filters on the data.